# Creating Classes to find the Side length and area of a figure

Tags: python

The question is: Create a class `Shape` that takes a list of two dimensional vertices as an input. For example:

```
tri = Shape([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0]])
# or
sqr = Shape([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1], [1,0]])
```

The class should store two attributes, the vertices themselves in `self.verts` and the number of vertices in `self.n`. Then class should have a method `calcSideLength()` that takes an integer argument between 0 and the number of sides of the shape and returns the length of the side. For example the shape:

```
tri = Shape([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0]])
```

has three sides `SIDE0: [0,0] --- [0,1]` `SIDE1: [0,1] --- [1,0]` and `SIDE2: [1,0] --- [0,0]`.

The length of each side is given by the Euclidean distance:

```
sqrt((1−′1)^2+(2−′2)^2)
```

so the lengths of the three sides would be 1, 1.414, and 1.

Then create a new class `Triangle` which is a child class of `Shape`. It should include a new method `calculateArea()` that returns the area of the triangle. This is, of course, 1/2×ℎ×ℎℎ . The length and height are the shorter two sides of the triangle.

This is what I got:

```
import math
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, verts):
        self.verts = verts
        self.n = len(self.verts)

    def calcSideLength(self,side):
        if(0 <= side < self.n):
            x1 = self.verts[side]
            x2 = self.verts[side+1]
        return math.sqrt((x1[0]-x2[0])**2 + (x1[1]-x2[1])**2)

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, verts):
        Shape.__init__(self, verts)
    

    def calculateArea(self):
        side = []      
        for i in range(self.n):
            side.append(self.calcSideLength(i))
            side.sort()
            area = 1/2 * side[1]* side[0]
            return area
```

THe code is not working, I do not know what went wrong, can anyone help with it please

Comment: What do you mean by *"The code is not working, I do not know what went wrong"*? Pick a specific example and show us the output and explain why it's wrong. Then reason through your code (and/or use `print` statements.) (I'm guessing this is homework and it's being rejected by an automatic grader. But you have to figure out a specific example why it's wrong.)

Comment: One obvious thing: your indentation is wrong, the methods aren't indented so they don't belong to `Shape` and `Triangle` class, they'll just behave like ordinary functions (and in fact the second `def __init__()` will overwrite the first). Please fix that then recheck everything.

Comment: BTW are you sure the area formula of a triagle is correct? You only have sides, _not_ a true height. From sides to a height, you would need trigonometry, unless the triangle is a right triangle.

Comment: I edited your message, with some tags for code and adjusting your indentation. As others noted, the math is wrong. Moreover, in the for loop inside `calculateArea`, the `return` indentation is wrong. It returns at the end of the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you name methods using not CamelCase but snake_case. Read PEP8 before writing a code.

Also you do not have to override your parent's init with super call as it's redundant

At third, you will have a problem when you will try to calculate last side length, because you have to x1 to be last vertice and x2 the first (this logic does not appear in your code)

At fourth, you are calculating area with a `1/2 * side * heigth`, but your none of your sides do represent a height, so instead you must use Heron's formula

```
S = sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))
```

where `a, b, c` are sides length and `p = (a + b + c) / 2`

Considering everything above, your code must look something like this

```
import math


class Shape:
    def __init__(self, verts):
        self.verts = verts
        self.n = len(self.verts)

    def calc_side_length(self, side):
        if 0 <= side < self.n - 1:
            x1 = self.verts[side]
            x2 = self.verts[side + 1]

        elif side == self.n - 1:
            x1 = self.verts[side]
            x2 = self.verts[0]

        else:
            raise

        return math.sqrt((x1[0] - x2[0]) ** 2 + (x1[1] - x2[1]) ** 2)


class Triangle(Shape):

    def calculate_area(self):
        sides = []
        for i in range(self.n):
            sides.append(self.calc_side_length(i))

        p = sum(sides) / 2  # p = (a + b + c) / 2

        return math.sqrt(p * (p - sides[0]) * (p - sides[1]) * (p - sides[2]))
```